# vertical scrollBar in JavaFX TableView should be down when it appear first time

Tags: javafx, javafx-2, javafx-8

Using JavaFX I am rendering huge amount of rows in tableView. So My requirement is that when the tableview renders the vertical scrollbar should be down. I created this with the help of **scrollTo().** But after that I am not able to scroll the tableView. Its always coming down and not able to see the previous view.

```
Platform.runLater(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
    int n = dataTable.getItems().size();
    if (n > 10)
        dataTable.scrollTo(n);
    }
});
```

Does anyone have any idea what to do?

Comment: This works fine for me (though I didn't use `Platform.runLater()`; I'm not sure why you need that). Can you create an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and edit your question to include it?